# Definite "root directory" for UIWebView using local files

Tags: html, ios, swift, webview, uiwebview

I am using an UIWebView to load html-documents from a local directory inside the Application. The html files contain absolute URLs, e.g.:
`index.html` in Documents-directory contains a link to `/css/main.css`. Unfortunately these absolute paths are not working, as the root directory for the WebView is not the Documents folder.

I tried to output the pathname with javascript and `alert(window.location.pathname);` had the following output:

[image]

So probably an absolute path would have to look like `/Users/.../Application/.../Documents/css/main.css`

Is there any possibility to set the root directory of the UIWebView to the Documents path? The URL `href="/css/main.css"` needs to point to `../Documents/css/main.css.`

Swift Code:

```
webView.loadRequest(
        URLRequest(url: URL.init(
               fileURLWithPath: "index.html",
               isDirectory: false,
               relativeTo: FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        )
    )
)
```

Thanks in advance